# Moving Umbraco Website to Azure

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm new to Umbraco. I'm tasked to move our website (which runs on Umbraco 7.4) to Azure.

I've decided to go with App Service for the site.

My question is what is the best approach to getting our current instance of Umbraco on Azure? The options I'm thinking of are:

**Option 1**

1. App:

a) Use Azure's marketplace and install Umbraco CMS

b) Copy the folders from Umbraco on our current server to Azure web app server folder

2. Database

a) Export databases from our current server and import to new Azure database

**Option 2**

1. App

a) Create Azure Web App

b) Same as Option 1 above, copy the folders from Umbraco on our current server to Azure web app server folder

2. Database
Same as Option 1

Basically is at simple as just copying (download) the "Umbraco" folder from our current server to new Azure web app server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Copying the files (and the database, of course) should be fine, Umbraco doesn't "install" anything outside the website itself :-) Either way should work though.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought that would be the approach.  However, not sure what "files" to copy.  We have Umbraco and our web apps all under webroot and not sure exactly what DLLs to copy from bin.  I guess I can compare the DLL files created in an Umbraco install to our webroot\bin and copy those over?  Also, assume I should copy all folders (App_Browsers, App_Config, etc.) in the from server and copy all those folders that show up in an Umbraco install.

Comment: As long as your website has it's own folder, copy the whole thing. There shouldn't be anything "not necessary" in there.